# Vue JS : Href link is not the same as data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, href

I have this `<a>` href below that if clicked will redirect me to

the `page.publicWebsite` value is [www.duckduckgo.com](http://www.duckduckgo.com)

`{{page.publicWebsite}}` displays [www.duckduckgo.com](http://www.duckduckgo.com)
HTML show [www.duckduckgo.com](http://www.duckduckgo.com) in the `href` so everything good ?

[image]

But when I click on the link I go to https://mywebsite/currentpage/www.duckduckgo.com

```
<a v-if="page.publicWebsite" target="_blank" :href="page.publicWebsite" :title="page.publicWebsite">{{page.publicWebsite}}<img src='/img/layout/icon-www.png' class='userInfoIcons' /></a>
```

Comment: work with Vue-Router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `href` treats your URL as a relative URL.
You've got to declare it as an absolute URL, one of two ways:

```
page.publicWebsite = 'https://www.duckduckgo.com'
// or
page.publicWebsite = '//www.duckduckgo.com'
```